# Deleting Preceding Blank Columns and Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to cycle through each sheet in the active workbook and delete all blank columns and rows leading up to the first cell with data. For example, if the first cell with data is D5, columns A-C and Rows 1-4 would be deleted leaving the data starting in A1. I have the code below which works for the active sheet but I can't figure out how to get it to loop through the other sheets.

```
Sub DeleteRowsColumns()
' This will delete all Blank Columns and Rows before any data
    Dim ColCounter As Long
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    Dim SafeCount As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    SafeCount = 0
' Check Column A is empty if Yes then Delete till A is populated
    
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    Do While ColCounter = 0
        SafeCount = SafeCount + 1
        ColCounter = Application.CountA(Columns(1).EntireColumn)
        If ColCounter = 0 Then
            Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
        If SafeCount = 50 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

Next ws

' Check Row 1 is empty if Yes then Delete till 1 is populated

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    SafeCount = 0
    Do While RowCounter = 0
        SafeCount = SafeCount + 1
        RowCounter = Application.CountA(Rows(1).EntireRow)
        If RowCounter = 0 Then
            Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        If SafeCount = 50 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    'Loop

Next ws

MsgBox "Removed Preceding Blank Rows and Columns"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within each loop you need to specify which worksheet you are performing the operations on.  Just looping through doesn't solve the problem.  For instance:

```
    ColCounter = Application.CountA(ws.Columns(1).EntireColumn)
    If ColCounter = 0 Then
        ws.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
```

This ensures you are working in the correct worksheet.

Add it to a loop.

```
For X = 1 To 50
    For i = 1 To 50
    ColCounter = Application.CountA(ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn)
        If ColCounter = 0 Then
            ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
        rowCounter = Application.CountA(ws.Rows(i).EntireRow)
        If rowCounter = 0 Then
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Next X
```

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid any looping by first finding where the content starts (by row and then by column)

```vb
Sub RemoveEmpties()
    Dim f As Range, f2 As Range, ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'first occupied cell on sheet (by row)
        Set f = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            'have content, so find first-occupied column
            Set f2 = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count), _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            'remove rows/columns as required
            If f.Row > 1 Then ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(f.Row - 1).EntireRow.Delete
            If f2.Column > 1 Then ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(, f2.Column - 1).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Alternatively (again only max of two deletes):

```vb
Sub RemoveEmpties2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, c As Long
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'first make sure there's some content on the sheet...
        If Application.CountA(ws.Cells) > 0 Then
            r = 1: c = 1
            Do While Application.CountA(ws.Rows(r)) = 0
                r = r + 1
            Loop
            If r > 1 Then ws.Rows(1).Resize(r - 1).Delete
            Do While Application.CountA(ws.Columns(c)) = 0
                c = c + 1
            Loop
            If c > 1 Then ws.Columns(1).Resize(, c - 1).Delete
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using the `Find` Method

**The Flow**

- In the procedure `delFirstBlank` the workbook is defined. A worksheet variable is declared. In the following `For Each Next` loop, for each worksheet in the workbook, the procedure `deleteFirstBlank` is called. When the loop exits, by a message box, the user is informed that the code has finished.
- In the `deleteFirstBlank` procedure, the result of the function `getFirstRow` is written to a variable. The variable is then tested if it is equal to `0` i.e. the worksheet is blank. If so, then the procedure is exited. If not, the variable is tested if it is greater than `1` i.e. if at least the first **row** is empty. If so, the **rows** from the first **row** to the **row** defined by the variable decreased by one are deleted. Then the result of the function `getFirstRow` is written to a variable which is tested if it is greater than `1` i.e. if at least the first **column** is empty. If so, the **columns** from the first **column** to the **column** defined by the variable decreased by one are deleted.
- In the `getFirstRow` procedure (function) a range variable is declared. Using the `Find` method, searching by **rows**, the first found non-blank cell (range) in the supplied worksheet, is assigned to the range variable. If the result of the `Find` method was a cell range, its **row** is written as the result of the function. If not, `0` is written as the result i.e. the worksheet is blank.
- In the `getFirstColumn` procedure (function) a range variable is declared. Using the `Find` method, searching by **columns**, the first found non-blank cell (range) in the supplied worksheet, is assigned to the range variable. If the result of the `Find` method was a cell range, its **column** is written as the result of the function. If not, `0` is written as the result i.e. the worksheet is blank (the latter will never happen, because the worksheet was already tested if it is blank in the 'getFirstRow' procedure).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub delFirstBlank()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        deleteFirstBlank ws
    Next ws
    MsgBox "Removed first blank rows and columns.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Sub deleteFirstBlank(Sheet As Worksheet)
    Dim Current As Long
    Current = getFirstRow(Sheet)
    If Current = 0 Then GoTo ProcExit ' Blank sheet.
    If Current > 1 Then
        Sheet.Range(Sheet.Rows(1), Sheet.Rows(CLng(Current) - 1)).Delete
    End If
    Current = getFirstColumn(Sheet)
    If Current > 1 Then
        Sheet.Range(Sheet.Columns(1), Sheet.Columns(CLng(Current) - 1)).Delete
    End If
ProcExit:
End Sub

Function getFirstRow(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, _
                                                  Sheet.Columns.Count), _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        getFirstRow = rng.Row
    Else
        getFirstRow = 0 ' Blank Sheet
    End If
End Function

Function getFirstColumn(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, _
                                                  Sheet.Columns.Count), _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        getFirstColumn = rng.Column
    Else
        getFirstColumn = 0 ' Blank Sheet
    End If
End Function
```